# Click on webview and on listener at the same time

Tags: android, webview, onclick

I have an invisible listener above of webview and i want that when the user click on this area, the invisible listener does something and if the web has some button, it does like if the invisible listener doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the use of Javascript interfaces within WebView. Please see [this area of the Android Developers Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript). Basically, you should be able to communicate from the page to the device with the Javascript interface and let your WebView Activity know whether the button on the page is present or not.

Comment: Thanks for your support!!! i can launch events with it, but if i don't know the code of Java Script, can i get the names of the methods of the Java Script to filter it and take all that ends with "and" for example?