# Launch an event when click on an area of webview

Tags: android, events, webview, listener

I work with an webview and i want to launch one different event when the user clicks on each corner of webview. it is possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Click on webview and on listener at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845624/click-on-webview-and-on-listener-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place your WebView inside a RelativeLayout, set the WebView to fill the entire RelativeLayout, then add whatever elements you'd like to rest on top of the WebView using android:layout_alignParentTop, android:layout_alignParentLeft, etc.

Comment: Finally i used an invisible ImageView above of the webView and i catch the click through it, Thanks!